# tippecanoe: don't drop any points?

Tags: mapbox, mbtiles, tippecanoe

I have a GeoJSON file with about 30,000 points in. I would like to use [tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe) to turn this into a Mapbox tileset (an mbtiles file).

I would like to drop none of the points, and for the tileset only to be available between zoom levels 10 and 15.

This is what I'm using at the moment:

```
tippecanoe -f -r 1000000 --no-tiny-polygon-reduction -o ./points/myfile.mbtiles -z15 -Z10 ./points/myfile.geojson
```

I'm using the `-r 1000000` argument because I think this means "drop 1 point in 1000000".

However, this doesn't seem to be working - lots and lots of the points are missing at zoom level 10.

How can I force tippecanoe not to delete any of the points?

NB I'm using tippecanoe rather than uploading the GeoJSON file directly to Mapbox because otherwise the tiles aren't available at zoom level 15, which I need them to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe):

> -B zoom or --base-zoom=zoom: Base zoom, the level at and above which all points are included in the tiles (default maxzoom).

So, you want `-B 10`.